# apache php7 session.save_path always point to /path

Tags: apache2, php7

I configured correctly in  /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

```
session.save_path = "/tmp/N;MODE;/"
```

But I am always getting the same error

```
Warning: session_start(): open(/path/sess_1ev4h097ni146fk3uuog5otpa1, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied
```

Whatever i do it always point to /path

any idea?

Comment: do you use mod_php, php-fcgi or something else? How does apache call/connects to php?

Answer (score 0):

( A litle *stupid* solution )

If you do not know if you use mod_php or a cgi-like, try to find where this path (session.save_path = /path ...) is set and change it to the one you want:

```
grep -R '/path' /etc/php/
```

This command should produce the filename in where you should set the path for your session.
Alternatively, you can do this :

```
grep -RE '^session.save_path' /etc/php
```

Then change all occurence to the path you want.